# Make height of parent div of froala editor scalable

Tags: jquery, css, froala

I am using froala  2.4.0 inline editor to implement facebook post-like feature. I have emebeded froala editor in a div as shown in image below.Now I would like to make the parent div scalable i.e. grow / shrink as the content of the froala editor changes.The bordered box is the parent div and the placeholder line is the froala inline editor.Is there any way to do this?[image]

This is what I got so far:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#custom-post-feed-text').froalaEditor({
    toolbarInline: true,
    charCounterCount: false,
    placeholderText: 'Share what\'s on your mind...',
    toolbarButtons: [],
    quickInsertButtons: []
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.4.0/css/froala_editor.pkgd.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.4.0/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-post-feed-container" id="custom-post-feed-container-personal">
  <div class="custom-post-feed-textarea">
    <textarea id="custom-post-feed-text"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-post-feed-options">
    <span class="custom-post-feed-more-options" id="custom-feed-more-options" title="More">+</span>
    <span id="more-option">
      <span title="Upload image"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <span title="Embed link"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <span title="Upload video"><i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <span title="Add Poll"><i class="fa fa-pie-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also I would like to know if there is any focus event that I can use.I need to execute some code once the user focuses the editor.The normal .focus() function of jquery is not working in this case.

Comment: have you tried autosize.js?

Comment: The div should expand unless you've set a height somewhere. Can we see more of your code or a full live example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Froala editor supports autogrow feature where you can set a `heightMin` and m`and`heightMax` and will auto grow in height as user types. See the docs

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/adjustable-height

```
$(function() {
  $('#custom-post-feed-text').froalaEditor({
    toolbarInline: true,
    charCounterCount: false,
    placeholderText: 'Share what\'s on your mind...',
    toolbarButtons: [],
    quickInsertButtons: []
    heightMin: 50,
    heightMax: 200
  })
});
```

For you purpose if the parent div does not have any fixed height for `custom-post-feed-textarea` it will auto grow